# Segmentation free license plate recognition model problem

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Our team aims to create a model for segmentation-free license plate recognition, with following architecture:

[image: Model architecture]

We have succesfully implemeted most of the architecture, but we are struggling with connection of 8 branches of fully connected layers (each of them for one character of license plate).

Is there a way to use same input (the `25x5x128` tensor) for each of the 8 branches and let them work independently and compare their outputs independently with corresponding ground truth letter of a license plate and punish (loss function) based on which letters were incorrect?

We have tried multiple approaches using keras models (both Sequential and Model class API) but without any luck. Below is our current version of model. We would greatly appreciate any help.

```
model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), use_bias=False, input_shape=(32, 32, 3),padding='same'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Activation("relu"))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), use_bias=False, input_shape=(32, 32, 3),padding='same'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Activation("relu"))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), use_bias=False, input_shape=(32, 32, 3),padding='same'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Activation("relu"))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), use_bias=False, input_shape=(100, 20, 32),padding='same'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Activation("relu"))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), use_bias=False, input_shape=(100, 20, 32),padding='same'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Activation("relu"))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), use_bias=False, input_shape=(100, 20, 32),padding='same'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Activation("relu"))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), use_bias=False, input_shape=(50, 10, 64),padding='same'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Activation("relu"))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), use_bias=False, input_shape=(50, 10, 64),padding='same'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Activation("relu"))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), use_bias=False, input_shape=(50, 10, 64),padding='same'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Activation("relu"))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))


model.add(layers.Flatten())


branch1 = models.Sequential()

branch1 .add(layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(16000,)))
branch1.add(layers.Dense(36, input_shape=(128,)))
branch1.add(layers.Activation("softmax"))

# Another 7 branches follows with exact same definition

final_model = keras.Model(inputs=[model, model, model, model, model, model, model, model],
                          outputs=[branch1, branch2, branch3, branch4, branch5, branch6, branch7, branch8])


final_model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        metrics=['accuracy'])

history = final_model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=80,
                          validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a dummy example

```
inp_dim = (32, 32, 3)
x_inp = Input(shape=inp_dim)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), use_bias=False, padding='same')(x_inp)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
x_out = Flatten()(x)
model = Model(x_inp, x_out)

inp = Input(shape=inp_dim)

branches = []

for _ in range(8):

    init_branch = model(inp)
    x = Dense(128)(init_branch)
    x = Dense(36)(x)
    x = Activation("softmax")(x)

    branches.append(x)

final_model = Model(inputs = inp, outputs = branches)


final_model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
                loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                metrics=['accuracy'])
```

the input is a SINGLE model (I used a simplified version) for all the 8 final branches. Check for the input dimension ((32, 32, 3) I don't know if it's correct)

---

this is my solution for correctly fit (It's a mine opinion, I don't test it)

```
import string

# dummy target in the format I expected (7 digits)
train_labels = np.array([['7C24698'], ['7F84698']])
test_label = np.array([['8C24698'], ['8F84698']])

# create dict to encode digits to numbers
y_map = {}
for i,d in enumerate(string.digits+string.ascii_uppercase):
    y_map[d] = i

# utility function for split string in char and encode them
def split_encode(x):
    x = list(x[0])
    x = [y_map[d] for d in x]
    return x

# transform target
train_labels = np.apply_along_axis(split_encode, 1, train_labels)
test_label = np.apply_along_axis(split_encode, 1, test_label)

......

# fit model (this works with 7 output branches, 36 digits output prob, and sparse_catcrossent
final_model.fit(train_images, [train_labels[:,i] for i in range(7)], epochs=80,
            validation_data=(test_images, [test_label[:,i] for i in range(7)]))
```

Comment: The model is now correct and I'm trying to write our own custom loss function. Problem is in shapes of y_pred and y_true. The y_true shape is 8 arrays of 36 probabilities (from each brach 36 probabilities) and the y_pred shape is just a string of 8 characters with correct licenseplate. Dont you have an idea how could we make the loss function work, as the loss function must have params with same shapes? Thank you for effort.

Comment: I'm receiving an following error: ```ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 8 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([['7C24698'],...```

Comment: I understand... but why len('7C24698') == 7 and not 8 as you expected? (this is not the reason for the error, only a consideration)

Comment: We expect 4th character to be always blank (if you check european license plates). Thats why we have 36 characters probabilities (A-Z, 0-9, blank symbol). So output of 4th branch should be hardcoded to compare with ground-truth blank symbol, then there is no need to include it into ground truth license plate.

Comment: I've tried to either "flatten" output of these 8 branches into one 1D vector of probabilities, or convert ground truth license plate to array of dimensions (8,36,1) - that should be output of our net - but none of them worked for me. I keep getting value errors. :/ I've found on the internet that loss function args (pred and true) may have different shapes, but doesn't work for me, i guess on the colab is old version of keras.

Comment: in python... import string .... len(string.digits+string.ascii_uppercase+' ') == 37 not 36 , correct?

Comment: Yeah you are right, we will correct the architecture. But still the problem with loss function   remains.

Comment: In my opinion, the best solution is to use 7 branches (7 digits, the blank space doesn't matter, it's fixed and can be retrieved during post-process ... in this way, we have 36 characters probabilities) ok? and for this situation, I have a solution proposal

Comment: Yes, 36 characters probabilities for each of the 7 branches. Feel free to share the solution (e.g. by editing your answer), it would be greatly appreciated. :)